# Bind language switching to a key combination in Win7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, language

I have 3 languages on my computer (has recently added French) and switching them with default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is really annoying, because sometimes you can type the wrong symbol if you forget the language you are using at the moment. I use French, but not so often as the other two.

**So, my question is**: can one bind a certain key or key combination to switch to only this one language?

Comment: Okay, guys, the question is closed, because I've found `Autohotkey`, and it suits all my needs. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Ah, and for anyone interested, [here's a link](http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?id=189) to the script threads.
I've binded the language switching to Capslock too. It still functions, but you need to press `Shift` + `Capslock` instead. 

    `+CAPSLOCK::CAPSLOCK
    Capslock:: 
        Send {Shift Down}{Alt Down}{Alt Up}{Shift Up}
    RETURN`

French language is not on the panel, so it doesn't get in the way when cycling through languages with Capslock, but I can switch to it by pressing `RCtrl`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the Steps:

1. Open **Control Panel**
2. Tap **Clock, Language, and Region**.

[image: Clock, Language, and Region]

3. Choose **Language**.

[image: Language]

4. Open **Advanced settings**.

[image: Advanced settings]

5. Click **Change language bar hot keys**.

[image: Change language bar hot keys]

6. Select the Language for which you want the short-cut (In my case **Hindi**) & click **Change Key Sequence**.

[image: Change Key Sequence]

7. Select **Enable Key Sequence** & configure the Keyboard shortcut as required.

[image: Enable Key Sequence]

8. Click **OK** & yo are done.

Comment: OP is using Windows 7 where the instructions are slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It works, but the problem is, you can still access the third language with normal `alt` + `shift`. Is there a way to isolate it somehow?
And another thing, can one possibly change the key sequence? I guess you have to edit registry for this.

Comment: Yes you can isolate `Alt' + 'Shift` . Just select the **Between input languages** & then **Change Key Sequence**. Select them to **Not assigned** & you are done. Which key sequence you mean.?? Yes you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably setup a link which executes a script like [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2007/04/12/configuring-regional-and-language-options-international-settings-with-command-line-automation/) article shows (You can add key combinations to links).

Comment: And how exactly do I add them?

Comment: Welcome to superuser and thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately, this is not a good answer because it leaves the person who has a problem with a lot of stuff to figure out. Add some steps about what to do and screenshots. Please read [answer] before answering.